# Compiling Caffe C++ Classification Example

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I recently modified the Caffe [C++ classification example file](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp) and I am trying to recompile it. However, I'm having trouble linking a simple g++ compilation to the .hpp files in the include directory. I know this is a basic question but I can't seem to work it out - can someone help me work out how to compile this program? The compilation looks like this now:

```
g++ -I /home/jack/caffe/include classification.cpp -o classify
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
In file included from /home/jack/caffe/include/caffe/common.hpp:19:0,
    from /home/jack/caffe/include/caffe/blob.hpp:8,
    from /home/jack/caffe/include/caffe/caffe.hpp:7,
    from classification.cpp:1:
/home/jack/caffe/include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:34:23: fatal error: cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cublas_v2.h>
```

I'm running this on a machine without Nvidia GPUs so when I looked at the device_alternate.hpp file I realised this is calling a lot of cuda-related .hpp files as well which don't exist.

Comment: please post the exact command you are using for compilation, and the error message you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Shai, just updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, in order to help the compiler locate header files you need to add [`-I /path/to/include/folder`](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.htm) option to the compilation line:

```
~$ g++ -I /path/to/caffe/include myfile.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - unfortunately it seems like I've found some new compilation errors once it manages to find the Caffe .hpp files!

Comment: @JackSimpson you need to add more `-I` options to other tools, this time your `cuda` include folder. Try and see what flags caffe is using when compiling.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to build custom files in caffe, there are two ways

**The easy way**

- Make the necessary changes and keep the file ( in your case - classification.cpp ) inside a directory ( say test ) in examples folder in th
  e caffe root directory.
- run `make`. This will automatically add the necessary cxxflags and ldflags and compile your code and place the executable in the build/examples/test folder. This also ensure the flag **CPU_ONLY** is set ( as mentioned in the *Makefile.config* )

**The Hard way**

- Run make without the pretty print option ( mentioned inside *Makefile.config* ). You will be able to see the compile and link options used to build the examples and tools. You can copy and paste these options ( and make necessary changes to relative paths if used ) to compile your file

Hope this helps

**Edit**
As the op requested an easy way, it can be done as follows

This is a very **minimal example** and I encourage the OP to refer to full online documentation and example of cmake usage.

- Requirements

  - Caffe needs to be built with **cmake** - Relatively easy as the current master branch has CMakeLists and everything defined. Use the Cmake-gui or ccmake to set your options

Now, I am assuming you have a project structure as follows.

```
-project  
    - src  
         - class1.cpp
         - CMakeLists.txt ( to be added )
    - include
         - class1.hpp

    - main.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt ( to be added )
```

The CMakeLists.txt ( src ) needs to contain (*at minimum*) the following lines,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) # Optional in case of dependency on opencv 
add_library( c1 class1.cpp )
```

**Note:** In case class1 depends on other external libraries, the path to headers must be included using `include_directories`.

The CMakeLists.txt ( outermost ) needs to contain the following at *minimum*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(MyProject)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)

include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" )
add_subdirectory( src )

include_directories( "$Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS}" )
add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( MyProject ${OpenCV_LIBS} c1 ${Caffe_LIBRARIES} )
```

Now, the following commands from inside the project directory will create the executable `MyProject` inside the `build` folder.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

You can then run your program with `./MyProject (arguments)`

**EDIT 2**

Satisfying the requirement of building caffe with CMake is very important for this to work. You need to configure and generate the Makefiles using CMake. Use `cmake-gui` or `ccmake` for this purpose so that you can set your options like CPU_ONLY,  etc.

You should create a build directory inside caffe and execute the following for a basic setup

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -jX #X is the number of threads your CPU can handle
```

Now, the .cmake directory in your $HOME folder consists of the following
`/home/user/.cmake/packages/Caffe/<random_string>` file. This file points to the install location of caffe ( which is our build directory )

Now, the find_package command should run without errors for your other projects. And since you are using CMake you can keep your project folder outside the Caffe folder ( and it is better to keep it outside as the make process of caffe will try to build your files but it will fail )

**Note**: In case that the error persists, you can manually set the *Caffe_DIR* during  cmake configuration.

Comment: That helps a lot, the one problem I have though is that I have a main.cpp program and two other classes in their own cpp files (and associated header files). Is there any way you know with the easy way where I could get two two other files to compile as well?

Comment: The best way out is to write a Makefile / CMakeLists.txt for each of them, compile them into objects and link it to the main.cpp along with the dependencies. To know the dependencies, you can switch pretty print off in the Makefile.config and see the flags passed to compile the examples / tools in the make process of caffe. And yeah, I can't think of how it can be done with the easy way. Maybe if I get to know later, I will ping you.

Comment: Thank-you for that great explanation! One thing I'm slightly confused about it how cmake finds Caffe? The instruction "find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)" or "${Caffe_LIBRARIES}" doesn't tell it where the library is. Once I've compiled Caffe on my computer, did I did to give it extra information to point cmake to where it's libraries are?

Comment: Mostly, whenever you build using cmake, The CMAKE_MODULES_PATH variable gets updated thus providing you with access to the includes and libraries as defined by CaffeConfig.cmake

Comment: You can find a file in your home directory ( `~/.cmake/` ) which has information about caffe and path to the build directory, which contains the CaffeConfig.cmake.

Comment: I tried to ls -a and cat the .cmake file in the home directory but for some reason it isn't there (I'm using ubuntu).

Comment: I put the project file with the structure like you recommended in your answer in the examples directory of Caffe and I get this error:

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
By not providing "FindCaffe.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Caffe", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Caffe" with any of the following names:

    CaffeConfig.cmake
    caffe-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Caffe" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Caffe_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Caffe"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

Answer (score 1):

Change Makefile.config to set `CPU_ONLY := 1`

```
# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In `./caffe/include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp` you have

```
...

#ifdef CPU_ONLY  // CPU-only Caffe.

...

#else  // Normal GPU + CPU Caffe.

#include <cublas_v2.h>

...
```

This means it will try to include `cublas_v2.h` unless `CPU_ONLY` flag is defined.

Since your machine doesn't have Nvidia GPU, you have to define `CPU_ONLY` flag during compilation with `-DCPU_ONLY=1`

So your full compilation command should look like

```
g++ -DCPU_ONLY=1 -I /home/jack/caffe/include classification.cpp -o classify
```